# WCF MaxReceivedMessageSize Error

Tags: wcf, maxreceivedmessagesize

I am getting below error when calling a wcf service (wshttpbinding). I already set the MaxReceivedMessageSize to max value (2147483647). Can any one tell me whats wrong?

I am using " security mode="Message" ", is that a problem?

Error:
*The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element*

Config: (CLIENT)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsDemo" closeTimeout="00:15:00" openTimeout="00:15:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
          transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:15:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://demo.com/DemoServices/DemoProduct.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsDemo" contract="DemoService.IProducts"
        name="wsDemo">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Server Config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="LargeWS" name="GexaEnrollCustomer.GexaEnroll">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"
          name="wsDemo" contract="MyInterfaces.IProducts">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="wsMex"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://demo.com/DemoServices/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LargeWS">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentInstances="200" maxConcurrentSessions="200" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:15:00" openTimeout="00:15:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the error message states "*for incoming messages*", which leads me to believe that it is the server side throwing this error, not the client.  You probably need to set `MaxReceivedMessageSize` on the server too, in addition to the client.

Typically you would set both the client and the server's configs to the same sizes.

Comment: Yes. I did that. Here is server config. Look my first message.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change the maxBufferSize.